# How is Perl useful as a metadata tool?

Tags: perl

In [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=983669):

> Normally, you can simply hide a third-party product behind a
>   well-defined, abstract interface. In fact , we've always been able to
>   do so on any project we've worked on. But suppose you couldn't isolate
>   it that cleanly. What if you had to sprinkle certain statements
>   liberally throughout the code? Put that requirement in metadata, and
>   use some automatic mechanism, such as Aspects (see page 39 ) or Perl,
>   to insert the necessary statements into the code itself.

Here the author is referring to [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and Perl as tools that support "automatic mechanisms" for inserting metadata.

In my mind I envision some type of run-time injection of code.  How does Perl allow for "automatic mechanisms" for inserting metadata?

Comment: Run-time injection, or build-time injection?

Comment: yes, sounds to me like it's talking about build-time and mentioning Perl because of its strength as a file/string manipulation tool

Comment: @ysth - I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.  My Perl skills are extremely limited.  Can you post an answer with a relevant example?

Comment: I'd be thinking things like `HTML::Template` and similar.

Comment: More like Text::Template or Template::Toolkit if you're using Perl as a pre-processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip ahead to the section on Code Generators. The author provides a number of examples of processing input files to generate code, including this one:

> Another example of melding environments using code generators happens when different programming languages are used in the same application. In order to communicate, each code base will need some information in commondata structures, message formats, and field names, for example. Rather than duplicate this information, use a code generator. Sometimes you can parse the information out of the source files of one language and use it to generate code in a second language. Often, though, it is simpler to express it in a simpler, language-neutral representation and generate the code for both languages, as shown in Figure 3.4 on the following page. Also see the answer to Exercise 13 on page 286 for an example of how to separate the parsing of the flat file representation from code generation.

The answer to Exercise 13 is a set of Perl programs used to generate C and Pascal data structures from a common input file.

Comment: The requirement is `What if you had to sprinkle certain statements liberally throughout the code? `...this is a pure decoupling problem no?  Code generation addresses DRY problems.  So I don't understand how this answers the question.  Am I missing something?

Comment: After more thought perhaps the author is offering two ways to solve the problem:  AOP (in a put the code somewhere else strategy) or Perl in a token replacement strategy.  This way the answer of string replacement makes sense.  If I need to update my code I simply update the value I'm inserting for the token (a DRY strategy).

Comment: Exactly. The author is referring to string replacement when he mentions Perl because it's synonymous with text processing.